# How would I reference a custom library made with another library in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opengl, dll

I'm currently building an FPS and am finished working on the game engine. I am now moving on to the game itself, but I have a slight problem.

I want to use my game engine, but I need to export it as a library in Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express. I also am using the OpenGL and GLUT libraries alongside my game engine (I needed it for rendering purposes).

How would I add export the game engine (as .dll or .lib?) and then reference it and everything in it inside another project within Visual Studio?

Comment: I have some trouble following what it is you're asking. Are you essentially asking if you build a DLL, how you can use the functionality contained within it in other code?

Comment: In a sense yes, but I would also like to know if I should use a .lib instead of a .dll? If not, then your question just about sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very detailed walkthrough for VS 2010 about the process of creating a DLL and referencing it in another project:

[Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You have already done some of these steps, so you can follow the rest to get everything working.

In short,

1. Generate a DLL and a LIB from your library project.
2. Reference the LIB at compile-time from your application project.
3. Provide the library DLL at run-time in the same directory as the application EXE.